# Python 3.9 - Unitesting method in class

Tags: python, unit-testing

Begginer level question, I am quite new and wanted to learn using unit test in my code. I've watched some tutorials how to make unittests, but when comes to practice it on your own code I start wonder how to make it properly to avoid learn bad code habits.

I have a class Geometry that will be inherited by other class, that class use imported custom object (namedtuple "Point") and list from json file with configuration but this will be provided by other part of code. Here are my questions:

1. Does my unittests should only check class methods create_geometry and calculate_drag_surfaces or also all mentioned above and instance creation with **init** method ?
2. When I create unitest of method that affect instance property, like create_geometry method do, how asserts should look like ? I should check value of changed instance property or there is a way to test it "in-place" without new instance creation ?
3. How should I make unittest for protected or hidden methods, I mean is there any difference there ?

If you will find any issues in my code I'm open to hear any suggestions I don't have any commercial experience and want to learn as much as I can. Below I presented code I want to test with unittest.

```
from point import Point


class Geometry:
    """
    Geometry class - object that will keep geometry dependent information necessary for
    graphic render and physic calculations
    """
    def __init__(self, geometry_points_cords, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry_points = []  # list of named tuples with co-ords on flat surface
        self.__create_geometry(geometry_points_cords)
        self.x_drag_surface = None
        self.y_drag_surface = None
        self.__calculate_drag_surfaces()

    def __create_geometry(self, geometry_points_cords):
        """
        Method that will convert provided geometry points into namedtuples that describe
        geometry on x/y plane
        :param geometry_points_cords:
        :return:
        """
        for geometry_cords in geometry_points_cords:
            self.geometry_points.append(Point(geometry_cords[0], geometry_cords[1]))

    def __calculate_drag_surfaces(self):
        """
        Method that will calculate drag surfaces in each axis base on geometry
        :return:
        """
        x_cords = []
        y_cords = []
        for single_point in self.geometry_points:
            x_cords.append(single_point.x)
            y_cords.append(single_point.y)
        self.x_drag_surface = (max(x_cords) - min(x_cords))**2
        self.y_drag_surface = (max(y_cords) - min(y_cords))**2
```

Comment: What is the specification of the Geometry class? Currently you only have a constructor (+ helper methods for it), no real behavior.

Comment: This are all functionalities that Geometry class will have - I try to divide my code into smallest possible functionality pieces. Geometry class itself will be use in other class that will represent physical object and will be one of property that physical_object will have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the interface the two fields `x_drag_surface` and `y_drag_surface`? Then you should primarily test that those get the proper values.

```py
geometry = Geometry(some_coordinates)
assert geometry.x_drag_surface = correct_x_drag_surface
assert geometry.y_drag_surface = correct_y_drag_surface
```

As the code is written now you can not test `__create_geometry` and `__calculate_drag_surfaces` separately since they will both be run by the constructor. You can extract them from the class, though, and make them testable:

```py
def make_points(coordinates):
    """
    Method that will convert provided geometry points into namedtuples that describr geometry on x/y plane
    :param geometry_points_cords:
    :return:
    """
    return [ Point(x, y) for (x, y) in coordinates]


def calculate_drag_surfaces(points):
    """
    Method that will calculate drag surfaces in each axis base on geometry
    :return:
    """
    x_coords = list(map(lambda p: p.x, points))
    y_coords = list(map(lambda p: p.y, points))
    
    x_drag_surface = (max(x_coords) - min(x_coords))**2
    y_drag_surface = (max(y_coords) - min(y_coords))**2

    return x_drag_surface, y_drag_surface


class Geometry:
    """
    Geometry class - object that will keep geometry dependent information necessary for
    graphic render and physic calculations
    """
    def __init__(self, coordinates, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry_points = make_points(coordinates)  # list of named tuples with co-ords on flat surface
        self.x_drag_surface, self.y_drag_surface = calculate_drag_surfaces(self.geometry_points)
```

Comment: So keeping in mind that code need to be tested, good practice is to methods always return results of action instead of modifying some class properties, right ?

Comment: As far as possible.

Comment: Another thing: Separate and mark tests of helper functions like `make_points` and `calculate_drag_surfaces` so that a later developer understands that those functions can be removed when the code is refactored.

Comment: I will make seprate file test_geometry.py with tests for that one. Thank you for your help.